# ListView inside NavigationView not scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I have been trying to make my NavigationView scrollable - to be able to view all items inside it. Earlier I had used menu items to populate my NavigationView, but the NavigationView didn't scroll. After searching about it a lot online, the most popular suggestion to make the NavigationView  scrollable seemed to be to use ListView inside NavigationView. I tried that, but my NavigationView still doesn't scroll.

Here is my XML:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="#1F262F"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:paddingTop="24dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        app:itemIconTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Please suggest a solution so that I can scroll down my NavigationView to view all items in it.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

did you tried using `ScrollView`?

Also, please notice `ListView` have now `layout_width="wrap_content"`.

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </ScrollView>            
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: unfortunately it's not working. Adding Scrollview, as suggested above,  makes all items of ListView disappear.